# The gravity center

Tags: centroid, local-systems

Good morning,

I want to prove that all points (A, B, C, D), as shown in the figure [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZX3R.png), compute the same center of gravity of the square.

Is there a way to prove that by using the local coordinates of the points (A, B, C, D) and translating them into the global system using the matrix and its inverse so they have the same center of gravity? The points do not necessarily have the same orientation.

The way to compute the gravity center is
$$
\bar c_i [t] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_j \bar r_j [t]
$$

and ri[t] is the coordinates of (A for exemple) at a moment t. N is the total number of points. So all the points use their own position coordiantes and the other points to calculate the same gravity center.

Comment: Your posting seems ambiguous to me, because it is unclear to me how changing one of the vertices of the rectangle affects the location of the other vertices.  However, what does seem clear to me is that regardless of how this (or any) rectangle is constructed, the two dimensional center of gravity of the rectangle is the exact point of intersection of the rectangle's two diagonals.  ...see next comment

Comment: So, if I have interpreted the problem correctly, one approach might be that whatever (**permissible**) method is used to alter the location of one or more of the rectangle's vertices $\color{red}{\text{will not change the location}}$ of the intersection of the rectangle's two diagonals.

Comment: @user2661923 I get you answer, thank you! However, I don't want to change one of the vertices. Since they all have different coordinates systems, I had an idea to translate them to one global system. Once this is done, I thought of calculating the new gravity center using their new coordinates, but I can't figure out if there is a proper method to show that they have the same gravity center.